# convert NSData to NSString always return nil

Tags: nsstring, google-drive-api, swift2, nsdata

I have a problem that I can't successfully convert NSData to NSString

I use google drive sdks to get content of my google doc using

```
var fetcher:GTMHTTPFetcher = service.fetcherService.fetcherWithURLString(downloadurl as! String)

fetcher.beginFetchWithCompletionHandler({(olddata:NSData!, error:NSError!) in
        if(error == nil) {
        print(olddata)
}

else {
        print("error is \(error)")
     }
})
```

olddata was a NSData (with no optional)
And I want to convert to NSString

but it always return nil when using basic conversion

```
let myStringFromData = NSString(data: olddata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

how can i fix this

Comment: print out olddata. it seems, that olddata doesn't represent utf8 encoded string.

Comment: @user3441734 yape because i think it might be utf8 because I upload the data using:

let data = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

so what I got from the GTMHTTPFetcher seems like to be utf8

Comment: @user3441734 and I am not sure because data that  I encode seems to be Optional(<0000 0000>) such as this, however the one I got from the old data was just <0000 0000, I am wondering whether this is the main problem I have faced

Comment: you declared it as NSData!, there is the reason for Optional. most interesting is what is inside. 00 00 00 00 is not valid utf8 sequence, so the result of NSString is nil. you received just four bytes with value 0x00

Comment: @user3441734  <0000 0000> is what I just take as example, sorry for let you misunderstand!  I have discovered that I declared NSData!, but that the data just couldn't be convert into NSString
the print in  olddata is like below<504b0304 14000808 08005541 6e470000 00000000 00000000 00001800>   

and I have try if my NSData has Optional<> than it can work for conversion, so the declaration of NSData! is what I thought it might cause my problem, but I couldn't fix it up! sorry for the wrong message provide.

Comment: @user3441734 btw because I though I have convert the data into utf8 because I have upload the data first to google drive and then I want to pull it down. I just couldn't figure it out whether the data I pull down is utf8 or not

Comment: what do you mean by 'convert the data into utf8'??

Comment: @user3441734 I mean that I have use "let data = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion:true) to set my content(String) into NSData before I upload them to google doc

Comment: yes! first check if it is not nil ... if let data = content.dataUsing........ { upload } content(String) is what? it is String?

Comment: @user3441734 yes! when I upload the data I have checked and it's not nil either. And the content I use was just a string

Comment: let utf8text = "alfa".utf8
let data = NSData(bytes: &utf8text, length: utf8text.count)

Comment: how did you create NSData ??

Comment: allowLossyConversion: true means that you will have some data, but not necessary valid utf8 byte sentence

Comment: you are not able to produce uft8 stream from 'any' binary data.

Comment: @user3441734 i think i know what you mean, so I misunderstand the dataUsingEncoding(NSSUTF8StringEncoding)? I thought it might product utf8 stream ... so I might use the way you create to produce utf8 ?

Comment: try it, it is easy and swifty   somestring.uft8 can not failed :-)

Comment: @user3441734 I tried that but it has error: 
Cannot convert value of type 'String.UTF8View' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Void>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')

let utf8content = content.utf8
let data = NSData(bytes: utf8content, length: utf8content.count)
just like this

Comment: var utf8text = "alfa".utf8
let data = NSData(bytes: &utf8text, length: utf8text.count)   so, or so. you can test all your code without sending nothing to the server, if you expect the same data to be received ...

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

let string = "what i would like to send to server as utf8 text"
var utf8text = string.utf8.map { $0 }
utf8text.append(0)
let data = NSData(bytes: &utf8text, length: utf8text.count)

// ..... upload, download, data is now received NSData from server

let p = UnsafePointer<Int8>(data.bytes)
if let received = String.fromCString(p) {

    print(received) // what i would like to send to server as utf8 text

}else {
    print("error by reconstructing string from data")
}
```

or

```
let string = "what i would like to send to server as utf8 text"
var buffer = string.nulTerminatedUTF8.map{ $0 }
let data = NSData(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count)

// ..... upload, download, data is now received NSData from server

let p = UnsafePointer<Int8>(data.bytes)
if let received = String.fromCString(p) {

    print(received) // what i would like to send to server as utf8 text

}else {
    print("error by reconstructing string from data")
}
```

or

```
let buffer = "what i would like to send to server as utf8 text".nulTerminatedUTF8
let data = buffer.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    NSData(bytes: $0.baseAddress, length: $0.count)
}
```